# Using Split function with Cells, Range, Rows.count, and xlup on excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

Will this code work?

```
lr = RD.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
wArray() = Split(RD.Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row))
RD.Cells(2, 8).Value = wArray(0)
RD.Cells(2, 9).Value = wArray(1)
```

I want the code to go through each of the cells in the range and split the data in that range and put the 2nd string on the cell next to it. Like for example, I have a `A1:A15` cell range that has the cell value of "01/01/2015 09:43 GMT", after I run the the code, I expect that "01/01/2015" will remain at range A1:A15 while "09:43" will be moved to cell range `B1:B15`. I have tried the same code by defining a single cell on the `Split(RD.Cells)` function and it worked beautifully. Now I need it to keep on going on the next row as long as that row has an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to loop through all the rows rather than only 1 row? If so you can try this.

```
lr = RD.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to lr
    wArray() = Split(RD.Range(Cells(i, 8))
    RD.Cells(i, 8).Value = wArray(0)
    RD.Cells(i, 9).Value = wArray(1)
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a loop

```
With RD.UsedRange
    .Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                              FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1))
End With
```